# Does Spark SQL 2.3+ support UDT?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was going through [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768?jql=text%20~%20%22public%20udt%22) and could not understand if Spark support UDT in  2.3+ version in any language (Scala, Python , Java, R) ?

I have class something like this

```java
Class Test{        
    string name;
    int age;
}
```

And My UDF method is:

```java
public Test UDFMethod(string name, int age){           
       Test ob = new Test();
       ob.name = name;           
       ob.age = age; 
}
```

Sample Spark query

```java
Select *, UDFMethod(name, age) From SomeTable;
```

Now `UDFMethod(name, age)` will return Test object. So will this work in Spark SQL after using `SQLUserDefinedType` tag and extending `UserDefinedType` class?

As `UserDefinedType` class was made private in Spark 2.0. I just want to know if UDT is supported in Spark 2.3+. If yes what is the best to use `UserDefinedType` or `UDTRegisteration`. As of now both are private in spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check, JIRA ticket you've linked has been delayed to at least Spark 3.0. So it means that there is no such option intended for public usage for now.

It is always possible to get around access limits (by reflection, by putting your own code in Spark namespace), but it is definitely not supported, and you shouldn't expect help, if it fails or breaks in the future.